# Trigonometry problem: How far below the surface of the hill is a point $38m$ down the tunnel?

Tags: trigonometry, slope

In the side of a hill that slopes upward at an angle of $32^\circ$, a tunnel is bored sloping downward at an angle of $12^\circ15'$ from the horizontal.

How far below the surface of the hill is a point $38$ meters down the tunnel?

Comment: What is " 12º15' from the horizontal"

Comment: What have you tried? We don't just *do* random problems without some effort or research on the poster's part.

Comment: The best advice is probably "Draw a diagram".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal distance from the tunnel entrance at a point $38$m along the tunnel is $h=38\cos(12.25°)$. Then the distance below the tunnel entrance is $v_1=38\sin(12.25°)$ and the corresponding distance of the hillside above that point is $v_2=h\tan(32°)$. The value you want is $v_1+v_2$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the issue here is that I can't sketch it

Comment: @HENPAUL added image

Comment: Very grateful,  I can complete the working

Comment: @HENPAUL For a future question, please, show a little what you have done on the subject.